# <img> flickering issue updating src with IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, flicker

I have a method which receives an image tag from the server and wants to append it to its container (imageHolder). It works perfectly for mac and windows browsers but windows/IE11. For this browser it flickers. Don't know how to solve this issue.

```
var holder = $('.imageHolder');
holder.empty().append(image);
...
```

Any idea??
Thanks in advance

Comment: you could try preloading the image...

Comment: I think Daniel is right. The flicker that you're seeing is because you have to wait for the image to download.

Comment: Thanks guys for your fast response. Then, why could this issue be happening on IE11 only?

Comment: @amanhuipg Are you really expecting Interwebs Exploder to behave sensibly? Oh the shame...

Comment: @amanhuipg It's possible that you don't notice it in Chrome or Firefox but it could still be happening. Try recreating the problem in something like jsfiddle and we'll see if it's truly just an IE11 problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were all right. I modified the code to change image src instead of removing/appending a new tag and now it works.

```
<div class="imageHolder">
    <img id="sharedImage" src="" alt=""/>
</div>
```

And then, using JQuery:

```
var sharedImage = $('#sharedImage');
sharedImage.attr('src', url);
```

Thanks for your help. I appreciate it.